# How do I show tabs but not spaces in Visual Studios?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I'm in a spaces-not-tabs house. I would like visual studio to show me when a tab is present (so I can destroy it). I have only been successful at showing ALL white-space.

My question is, how do I only show tab characters?

Comment: You can't.  But you can do a find and replace using regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have it "show" you, but you can do a find and replace with a regular expression:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools so that when you load a page it will display a message to you that you have file with Mixed Tabs.  It will give you a button to fix up the file for you.

The tool in the suite is called 'Fix Mixed Tabs'.

Scroll way down to see the very self explanatory explanation.

[Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace?SRC=Home)